# Prove $ |\vec{a_1}-\vec{b}|+ \cdots +|\vec{a_n}-\vec{b}| > n $

Tags: inequality

There are $ \vec{a_1},\vec{a_2},\vec{a_3}, \ldots ,\vec{a_n},\vec{b}\; $ such that $ |\vec{a_i}|>1 $, $ |\vec{b}|<1 $, $ \vec{a_1}+\cdots+\vec{a_n}=0 $
.Prove  : $ |\vec{a_1}-\vec{b}|+\cdots+ |\vec{a_n}-\vec{b}| > n $

Comment: Are you talking about...vectors? In the plane? In the space? What have you tried...?

Comment: I try $|\overrightarrow{{{a}_{1}}}-\vec{b}|+\cdots +|\overrightarrow{{{a}_{n}}}-\vec{b}|\ge |\overrightarrow{{{a}_{1}}}+\cdots +\overrightarrow{{{a}_{n}}}-n\vec{b}|=|n\vec{b}|>n$，but I use $|\overrightarrow{b}|>1$,not use $|\vec{a_i}|>1$,

Comment: @DonAntonio, I tried this, that's not enough to get the result. I guess the key is $\sum a_i=0$, but not sure how to use it. And geometryscience's inequality is correct, it is just a generalised version of triangle inequality.

Comment: I know it's not enough, @Easy, yet the above inequality that geom. wrote is then enough, without any condition on $\,|a_i|\,$...

Comment: The condition given is $|\vec{b}|<1$, not $|\vec{b}|>1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma**. Let $\vec{a}$ be a nonzero vector and $\vec{b}$ be another vector. Then $|\vec{a}-\vec{b}|\ge |\vec{a}|-\vec{b}\cdot\dfrac{\vec{a}}{|\vec{a}|}$.

*Proof of Lemma*. Use $|\vec{x}||\vec{y}|\ge \vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}$ for  $\vec{x}=\vec{a}-\vec{b}$ and $\vec{y}=\dfrac{\vec{a}}{|\vec{a}|}$.

**Proof**. Using the above lemma, we get
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^n|\vec{a_i}-\vec{b}|\\
&\ge \sum_{i=1}^n \left(|\vec{a_i}|-\vec{b}\cdot\frac{\vec{a_i}}{|\vec{a_i}|}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(1-\vec{b}\cdot\vec{a_i}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^n\left(|\vec{a_i}|-1+\vec{b}\cdot\frac{\vec{a_i}}{|\vec{a_i}|}\cdot (|\vec{a_i}|-1)\right)\\
&=n-\vec{b}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n \vec{a_i}+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{|\vec{a_i}|-1}{|\vec{a_i}|}(|\vec{a_i}|-\vec{b}\cdot\vec{a_i}).
\end{align*}

Here, the second term $\vec{b}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^n \vec{a_i}$ is zero. The third term is positive because $|a_i|>1$ and
$$|\vec{a_i}|>|\vec{b}||\vec{a_i}|\ge \vec{b}\cdot\vec{a_i}.$$
The first inequality follows from $|b|<1$. Hence
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|\vec{a_i}-\vec{b}|>n.$$